# lodash _.intersectionBy is not working in callback function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash intersectionBy method by "id" using angular js typescript callback function, but it is not working with id for some reason.  How can we intersection by id with callback function.

Here my try.

```
private filterOutputRelationFn: Function; // created declaration

 this.filterOutputRelationFn = _.intersectionBy; // defined

console.log(this.filterOutputRelationFn([{ 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x'));  // Not working by id

Expected result:
// => [{ 'x': 1 }]
```

**same way if I try with "_.intersection" It does work.**  What could be the issue in the above scenario.

```
 private filterOutputRelationFn: Function; // created declaration

 this.filterOutputRelationFn = _.intersection; // assigned

console.log(this.filterOutputRelationFn([{ 'x': 1 }], [{ 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }]));  // It works

Expected result
// => [{ 'x': 1 }]
```